# How to download all linked images from in HTML source code?

Tags: html, image, automation, web-scraping

**Overall mission:**
For the purpose of printing, I want to download 330 images that are linked from a Pinterest board. Note, not the thumbnails that you see when visiting a board, but the larger images that they link to.

**Context:**
Go to a Pinterest.com board of choice and view the source. The relevant hi-res image links can be seen in the page source within the atttribute `data-closeup-url`

**Example URL**
http://pinterest.com/stonegarden/misc/

The relevant board is invite-only, I reckon that may be relevant with regards to scripts not being 'logged in' etc.

My question is: How can I download all these 330 hi-res images from a board with the least effort? I.e with a script, with iMacros or anything else. The end result would be a folder that contains all these 330 images downloaded.

Edit, as requested:

**What I've tried so far**
I'm not using any specific programming language, my skills are limited in that field. Either way, I imagine the problem's gonna be the permissions.

1. Automating with the Firefox extension iMacros - fails because I can't get it to do anything useful with the image URLs and other reasons
2. The solution provided by Benno - I can paste the relevant URLs, but fails and says "No permissions for requested resource"

So, how does Pinterest differentiate between a user clicking a thumbnail to get the large image, and Safari trying to download the same resources via the Download window?

Comment: If this is a programming question (thus a good fit for the site) you should explicitly say what your programming language is and what you've tried so far. Otherwise, you can simply install [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) in your computer.

Comment: Note that this is **not data mining** (which is advanced data analysis). I removed the tag, and replaced it with [tag:web-scraping] instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and tips, I've tried to improve my question!

Answer (score 2):

Open up your browser's web inspector and go to the Console.

Put in this code:

```
var s = ''; $('div[data-closeup-url]').each(function() { 
s+= $(this).data('closeup-url') + "\n"; 
}); s;
```

That will give you the URLs of all the images, then you can just copy and paste them into a URL capturing utility like jdownloader. Takes away the need to do anything related to logging in to their server. Or just write a script to file_get_contents (php) for each URL.

If you use Safari, open the download window and paste the list of URL's into the download window (ctrl+v or cmd+v) and it downloads all of them (tested in safari 6 on mac)

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, just displaying the Downloads window in Safari (version 6.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5), I can't paste anything. How do you get to the download window you refer to?

Comment: Hmm... you know when you download something, it shows that little blue progress bar in the top right of the window? I just downloaded something random, clicked on the blue bar, clicked in the window pane near where it was downloading and typed cmd+v... Is that what you have in your version? i have 6.0.2 as well, but I have mountain lion). Can't right click paste, only worked with cmd+v... weird if you can't do that :S

Comment: I almost got it working now, I had some unneeded characters in the beginning of the string I pasted. 

So now it accepts my pasting, but gives me "No permission for the requested resource", although I am logged in to Pinterest on this machine on Safari.

Comment: Hm that's weird, because I downloaded the ones in the link you provided easily? The 550px wide links generated by that script. Whats the URL you are trying to download? What are the unneeded characters? Should just be the quotes of the console logging the string (can remove those)?